# Python: How to pass Dataframe Columns as parameters to a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, bert-language-model

I have a dataframe `df` with 2 columns of text embeddings namely `embedding_1` and `embedding_2`. I want to create a third column in `df` named `distances` which should contain the cosine_similarity between every row of `embedding_1` and `embedding_2`.

But when I try to implement this using the following code I get a `ValueError`.

How to fix it?

**Dataframe `df`**

```
           embedding_1              |            embedding_2                                 
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.49163356, -0.4877703,...]]
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.06686627, -0.75147504...]]
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.42776933, -0.88310856,...]]
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.6520882, -1.049325,...]]
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-1.4216679, -0.8930428,...]]
```

**Code to Calculate Cosine Similarity**

```
df['distances'] = cosine_similarity(df['embeddings_1'], df['embeddings_2'])
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**Required Dataframe**

```
       embedding_1              |            embedding_2                 |  distances                        
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.49163356, -0.4877703,...]]   |    0.427
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.06686627, -0.75147504...]]   |    0.673
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.42776933, -0.88310856,...]]  |    0.882
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-0.6520882, -1.049325,...]]     |    0.665
 [[-0.28876397, -0.6367827, ...]]   |  [[-1.4216679, -0.8930428,...]]    |    0.312
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to use `cosine_similarity()` on each row:

```py
def cal_cosine_similarity(row):
    return cosine_similarity(row['embeddings_1'], row['embeddings_2'])

df['distances'] = df.apply(cal_cosine_similarity, axis=1)
```

or one liner

```py
df['distances'] = df.apply(lambda row: cosine_similarity(row['embeddings_1'], row['embeddings_2']), axis=1)
```